# How do I generate a phase-potrait (by hand)?

Tags: dynamical-systems

> Create a list of all periodic points of f : $f (x) = x + sin x$ on R and
> use the graph of f to sketch its phase portrait. Identify the stable
> quantities for each of the periodic points.

What does the question mean?

"Create a list of all periodic points for f : $f (x) = x + sin x$ on $R$" ?

Then sketching the phase portrait, must be related to the actual periodic points one finds?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what a "periodic point" is?

Comment: Yes, it is a point where a new period of the system starts and ends.

Comment: Does it matter whether the periodic points do or do not intersect with the $x$-axis?

Comment: @Moo so one important necessity for periodic points is that they intersect with the $x$ axis?

Comment: Crystal clear! Thanks Moo

Comment: So the phase potrait would look like a circle around the origin, and several circles around that again with a distance between that equivocates to $n\pi$ perpendicular from the x-axis meeting with the plot of the function?